# @generatedvalue not working, still asking to manually assign id

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm learning spring-hibernate and trying to get my web service working, but now i'm stuck with this situation. My service for getting the data work well but when i try to post this condition happen :

1. i already use @generated value annotation
2. trying modif it's type like : GenerationType.SEQUENCE, IDENTITY, etc (none of them work either)

So far my best guess, so this is my code

This is my model class (part of it) the other is typical like email, phone, etc. And it dont have any relation to another table, only 1 table on my DB btw i use ms sql server

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Patient")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Patient implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "guidGenerator", strategy = "guid")
    @GeneratedValue( generator= "guidGenerator")
    @Column(name = "PatientGUID", columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")
    private String patientGuid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getPatientGuid() {
       return patientGuid;
    }

    public void setPatientGuid(String patientGuid) {
       this.patientGuid = patientGuid;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**Edit** : My hbm file

```
 <hibernate-mapping package="training.model">
 <class name="Patient" table="Patient">     
    <id name="patientGuid" type="string">
        <column name="PatientGUID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <property name="practiceGuid" type="string">
        <column name="PracticeGUID" sql-type="varchar" length="38" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="FirstName" sql-type="varchar" length="30" not-null="true" />
    </property>

    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="LastName" sql-type="varchar" length="30" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My table detail which i believed caused this problim is : **PatientGUID** and it's type is **UNIQUEIDENTIFIER**, when i execute my webservice and request POST method to post my patient i got an error, which is :

**ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()**

So guys i really need help, what did i do wrong or what did i miss? If you need any more detail on my code just leave a comment, thanks

**EDIT** : The ERROR Message

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually              assigned before calling save(): training.model.Patient
at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:52)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
at training.dao.PatientDaoImpl.savePatient(PatientDaoImpl.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.savePatient(Unknown Source)
at training.service.PatientServiceImpl.addPatient(PatientServiceImpl.java:29)
at training.ws.PatientWS.addPatients(PatientWS.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `guid` strategy in hibernate, there is however `uuid`. Following should work.

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "guidGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
```

Comment: i'm new to spring-hibernate, i tried with that and still no luck. Probably something i missed? maybe in another configuration like : hibernate.properties or hibernate.cfg.xml.